# How to read a file/image from outside of android project

Tags: android, android-image, android-file

I'm struggling with this for about 2 hours now. 
I'm just trying to read an image that is inside the folder on my desktop. 
Was trying many different ways but nothing works.

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\My logos\\";
String _image = "walcott.png";
File imgFile = new File(path+_image);
if(imgFile.exists())
{
 Log.d("OMG FILE EXIST!", imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Any ideas? Aww and the image is png.

Thanks!

Comment: Android cannot access your desktop! Presumably you're using the emulator on your local machine, but even that cannot see outside of the Android OS. You need to create a fake SDCard for the emulator, copy the file to it, and use the Android External Storage routines to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible, first off the code is running on an Android device so it's gonna search for a `C:/` disk on de device.

It is possible to get files from outside the app package by checking the sd card for particular files, but **still** an sd card on the device of course.

As example:

```
File sdCardLocation = new File(
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
    "//FolderOrFile//OnTheSDCard.png"
);

if(sdCardLocation.exists())
    Log.d("OMG SDCARD EXIST!", sdCardLocation.getAbsolutePath());
```

But you have to add this permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: And what if my device does not have SD card? Image is saved on internal storage like: Computer\Nexus 7\Internal storage\DCIM\.thumbnails.

Comment: @Jakubee If you have no SD it will automatically write to your internal storage on your device.

Comment: Still nothing. Is this correct directory: "Computer//Nexus 7//Internal storage//DCIM//.thumbnails//walcott.png". I have also tried with this:
File queryImg = new File(ImagePath);
int imageLen = (int)queryImg.length();
byte [] imgData = new byte[imageLen];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(queryImg);
fis.read(imgData); 

without success.

Comment: What directories do you see on your device? You may find the directory *Computer* in the root of the storage.